# Can ghc treat certain specified warnings as errors and others as warnings?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Can ghc somehow be convinced to treat certain types of warnings as errors and others as warnings, while still reporting them?

I hoped, this would be possible with something like this:

```
ghc -Werror -fwarn-missing-methods -Wwarn -fwarn-missing-signatures
```

, but I had no luck with that. (I think gcc doesn't support this either.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's an all-or-nothing switch. However, you can do

```
ghc -Werror -fwarn-missing-methods -fno-warn-missing-signatures
```

Although this causes GHC to swallow the warning completely, which might not be what you wanted.

Comment: No, that's exactly what I hoped to prevent.

Comment: This answer is now obsolete - check out the answer by [Alex R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52310/alex-r) above

Answer (score 8):

Note that starting GHC 8.2.1, this feature exists! It was described by Trac ticket [#11219](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11219) and now you can do `ghc -Werror=missing-methods -Wmissing-signatures`!

Answer (score 2):

If this is of great concern, you could consider enabling and disabling warnings on a per-module basis. So that in some modules you'd have:

```
 {-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall -Werror #-}
```

to here about everything, while in others:

```
 {-# OPTIONS_GHC -w -Werror -fwarn-missing-methods #-}
```

to only enable some things as errors.